# How to get the value of the last element of property in repeater

Tags: c#, html, asp.net, arrays, repeater

```
     <asp:Repeater ID="ReptServices" runat="server" OnItemDataBound="ReptServices_OnItemDataBound">
                      <b>
                  <td>    <%# Eval("ApplicationSteps") %></td>
                     <td><%# Eval("Service.ServiceName") %></td>
                            <td>
                                <b><%# Eval("BeneficiaryUserUnitJob.User.NameAr") %>  </b>
                            </td>
                            <td><%# Eval("DateCreated") %></td>
                      </b>
       </asp:Repeater>
```

this repeater filled in c# as

```
ReptServices.DataSource = new ApplicationLogic(ApplicationType.Web).GetAllOutboxApplication(_currentUserUnitJob);
```

"ApplicationSteps"property contains many elements,which contains another property called `submitactiontypeid` as this image shows:

[image]

I want to get the value of `submitactiontypeid` which exist in the last elment of `ApplicationSteps`

I asked what I shall write in  `<%# Eval("ApplicationSteps") %>`

Comment: So you need the value of `Eval("ApplicationSteps")` of the last `RepeaterItem`? Where?

Comment: sorry can't understand !!

Comment: It's not clear what you actually want and where do you need it.

Comment: Something like this may be helpfull for you : `<%# Container.ItemIndex + 1 == Items.Count ? "this is the last item" : null %>`

Comment: Seems too lazy but I try to create a new solution :) `<%# Container.ItemIndex + 1 == Items.Count ? ((ApplicationSteps)Items[Container.ItemIndex]).SubmitActionTypeId : null %>`

Comment: what container means ?, I am not lazy, believe me I'm just can't understand

Comment: No I mean my code seems too lazy sorry @sara. `Container` means; an instance of your repeaters next `RepeaterItem`. Just paste my code inside of the ItemTemplate. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.repeateritem%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Comment: @AhmetRemziEKMEKÇİ please see again my update 
because when I paste your code it can't recognize the ApplicationSteps

Answer (score 1):

I came with a different solution for you.

If you are not available to modify your code behind, still we don't need the repeater to solve.

```
<%
var repeaterDataSource = (dynamic)ReptServices.DataSource;
foreach (var item in repeaterDataSource)
{%>

<%=item.ApplicationSteps %>

<%}%>
```

This is your basic Repeater. Because of I do not know what your data type that you bind to the repater, I use dynamic type.

You can modify for your purpose.

```
<%=item.ApplicationSteps.Last().SubmitActionTypeId  %>
```

First, debug without adding this line. If it works fine, add the code above and try again.

Comment: when I do the first code it worked as its old without error , when I write the last one it gives me an error says `'System.Collections.Generic.HashSet<ESERV.DataMapping.Entity.ApplicationStep>' does not contain a definition for 'Last'`

Answer (score 0):

If you just need to render that value in the page then the `repeater` is useless. Try this code:

ASP

```
<asp:Label runat="server" ID="SubmitActionType"></asp:Label>
```

Then Server side (C#)

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;

public partial class WebForm1 : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var applicationSteps = GetApplicationSteps(); //Call the function that gives you the data you need

        var lastElement = applicationSteps.Last(); //Get the last element

        SubmitActionType.Text = lastElement.SubmitActionTypeId;
    }
}
```

The `repeater` is useful when you need to render some html for each value inside an array of objects. In this case you are clearly not doing that.

Comment: I can't modify in cs class I just available to edit in aspx

Comment: @saraadly any particular reason for that? Why can't you modify it?

Comment: also repeater data source filled dynamically from one query in c#

Comment: not of my privilege , also repeater filled as ` ReptServices.DataSource = new ApplicationLogic(ApplicationType.Web).GetAllOutboxApplication(_currentUserUnitJob);`

Comment: @saraadly that query is what you assing to the variable `applicationSteps`. The function `GetApplicationSteps` is a function I invented to imply that you should replace that code with the code that does the actual query and brings the data. You should give it a try and obviously in ASP.NET you have to modify your server side code if you want to change things and try different approaches.

Comment: @saraadly replace the line in my example that is like this `var applicationSteps = GetApplicationSteps();` with this `var applicationSteps = new ApplicationLogic(ApplicationType.Web).GetAllOutboxApplication(_currentUserUnitJo‌​b);` The rest should work as expected

Comment: So If I change the code as you said , from where shall the repeater other items filled with?

Comment: @saraadly You didn't state in the question that you needed any more items rendered. You said you just needed to render that property value from the last element in the page. Complete your question with all the code you have and what you need to get better help :)

Comment: @saraadly Sadly, it is still incomplete. I want to help you but you really need to elaborate more in what you actually need. I was going to update my answer but it is pointless right now. Try to make a draw of what you want to render in the page (how do you want the page to look) to see if we can better understand what you are trying to do.